# Image adjustment level is not working in photoshop cc 2015

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am beginner in photoshop and I am trying to add sunrays in my image but `Image<Adjustment<Levels` option is not activated and not working... I couldn't fix this issue, can anybody guide me what's the problem behind of it? I have CC 2015 Version of Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of the whole photoshop window with this menu open please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a number of things.

1. Make sure you're working in RGB as some of the adjustment options don't work with CMYK.
2. Make sure the layer you are trying to adjust is not locked or off.
3. Rasterise all layers before applying adjustment layers.
4. Adjustments can't be used in masked mode.

Comment: I have solved my problem by right click on the layer and select rasterize layer. Thank You @AasimAzam it's a helpful answer.

Answer (score -1):

1. Grab the eraser.
   Move it over the image (the eraser icon should change to a circle with a slash through the middle).
   Click on the image (it won't erase anything).
   A message will pop up, click "OK".

You should now be able to use image adjustments.

2. Go to menu -> image -> mode -> change indexed to RGB color